# How to run SQL Server 2012 on a multiple accounts

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have installed an application that connect to a SQL Server 2012 on a user account, now my customer need to run the application on another new user account, but I can't connect to the database from the new account. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to provider db permissions to the new user account. You can provide permission to the account in sql server 2012 by going to Security => Logins => Select User Account that needs permissions => Righ click and open properties => User Mapping => Then Select Database from the upper window and permissions type from the bottom.